# How can I download, uncompress and process a gzip file in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I would like my ocaml application to directly download, uncompress (gzip) and then process the resulting text file line by line without using a temporary file and external programms.

The libraries I looked at are *cohttp*, *ocurl* and *camlzip*. Unfortunately I found no nice way to make them work together.

What would be the way of OCaml to achive this?

Comment: I find no such library in the OPAM repo.  Probably there is none at this moment.

Comment: What's wrong with a temporary file?

Comment: I was just hoping that there was some simple straightforward way like in many other languages, such as: new GzipInputStream(url.openStream()).foreach(println)

Comment: @gruenewa unfortunately such things are often missing, this is a good chance to write such a thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make *ocurl* and *camlzip* work together by using pipes and threads. Proof of concept:

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#require "unix";;
#require "curl";;
#require "zip";;

let () = Curl.(global_init CURLINIT_GLOBALALL)

let download url oc =
  let open Curl in
  let h = init () in
  setopt h (CURLOPT_URL url);
  setopt h (CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION (fun x -> output_string oc x; String.length x));
  perform h;
  cleanup h

let read_line really_input =
  let buf = Buffer.create 256 in
  try
    while true do
      let x = " " in
      let () = really_input x 0 1 in
      if x = "\n" then raise Exit else Buffer.add_string buf x;
    done;
    assert false
  with
  | Exit -> Buffer.contents buf
  | End_of_file -> if Buffer.length buf = 0 then raise End_of_file else Buffer.contents buf

let curl_gzip_iter f url =
  let ic, oc = Unix.pipe () in
  let ic = Unix.in_channel_of_descr ic and oc = Unix.out_channel_of_descr oc in
  let t = Thread.create (fun () -> download url oc; close_out oc) () in
  let zic = Gzip.open_in_chan ic in
  let zii = Gzip.really_input zic in
  let () =
    try
      while true do
        let () = f (read_line zii) in ()
      done;
      assert false
    with
    | End_of_file -> ()
  in
  Gzip.close_in zic;
  Thread.join t

let () = curl_gzip_iter print_endline "file:///tmp/toto.gz"
```

It becomes painful when one has to handle errors, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get stuff done I'd drop the "no external programs" requirement and write the OCaml source code file `download_gunzip_lines.ml`:

```
open Printf

let read_all_lines ic =
  Seq.unfold (fun () -> try Some(input_line ic, ()) with _ -> None) ()

let () =
  match Sys.argv with
  | [|_; url|] ->
    read_all_lines(Unix.open_process_in(sprintf "wget -q -O - %s | gunzip" url))
    |> Seq.iter (fun line -> printf "%d\n" (String.length line))
  | _ -> eprintf "Usage: download_gunzip_lines <url>"
```

with the `dune` file:

```
(executable
 (name download_gunzip_lines)
 (libraries unix))
```

Then:

```
dune build --profile release
```

to build it and:

```
./_build/default/download_gunzip_lines.exe http://www.o-bible.com/download/kjv.gz
```

to run it on a copy of the King James Bible.

Better yet, run the `wget` and `gunzip` with your OCaml code from a Bash script and just process the lines in OCaml.